# How to use Selenium features from Selenium2 class?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm using PHPUnit and Selenium in my PHP project.

I have been following instruction at: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html. Currently I am able to start Selenium server and I've done few test classes extending either PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase or PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase class.

I've been using https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php as my reference for Selenium2 tests.

I was trying to find methods to implement keyPress functionality but I couldn't find it from PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase. It can be found from PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase.

**Question comes here:** can I use PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase functionality in my PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase classes? For instance, this keyPress functionality.

**Version info:**

PHPUnit: 3.6.10

selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHat do you need keypress for?

Not tested, but from the testcases you already refer to:

`$this->keys('phpunit ');`

would send the keypresses p, h, p, u, n, i, t and space.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:
For simulating human behavior typing keys:

```
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('TEXTHERE');
```

or

```
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
```

And yes you can use the functionailities as long as you call them.